# Ubuntu 16.04 does not see SSD

Tags: boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

I have a new Dell Latitude E7470 and I try to install Ubuntu on its SSD.
In the Bios the SSD is shown and the pre installed Windows works very well too.
I try to erase the Windows and install Ubuntu.

Ubuntu shows only the used USB stick as device and complains therefore of to little hard disk space.

In the Bios the SATA mode is "Raid on". As far as I know, this enables AHCI for SATA drives too.
So I do not know why Ubuntu does not detect my SSD drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like Intel Rapid storage is turned on. If so you need to turn off the RAID and use SATA or ACHI mode depending on your BIOS terminology

Disk caching a SSD to mSata cars has no performance benefits in Intel RST anyway it's only designed for HDD (hard disks)